# I am trying to populate checkbox true/false values in a windows form application from an xml document

Tags: xml, checkbox, binding

I may just need to be steered in the right direction, but I have a scenario where, on my main form I have a list of about 15 different checkboxes. When I check some of these boxes, I want to then be able to click my 'Save' button and have it store the bool value (1 for true, 2 for false) in the corresponding XML file.

My XML file is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Tests>
  <EngName></EngName>
  <Test Name="NavigatorLaunch" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Navigator_Links" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="CLR_ActiveEng" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Open_ActiveEng" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="CLR_ArchiveEng" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Open_ArchiveEng" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Replicate_ActiveEng" Value="0"></Test> 
  <Test Name="Org" Value="1"></Test>
  <Test Name="MAT" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="PA" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="CA" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Scoping" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="AR" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Controls" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GEToD" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GESA" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GEToC" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="DL" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="CDW" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="IM" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="TaskStatus" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="Dashboard" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="EngagementCheck" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="ER" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="AuraMenu" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GELoadTest" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="SM" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GE_TypeOfWork" Value="0"></Test>
  <Test Name="GE_TypeOfWork_UICheck" Value="0"></Test>
</Tests>
```

Any help would be great!

5/9 - An update of the code that I am attempting to use for this solution.. Still getting errors though. Object Reference. My syntax for my element is obviously not right, and I'm guessing I can't select my first attribute I want to base it off of from it.

```
var doc3 = XDocument.Load(xml_path2);
            var elem = doc3.XPathSelectElement("//Tests/Test[Name='NavigatorLaunch']");


            if (checkBoxNavigator.Checked == true)
            {
                elem.Attribute("Value").Value = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It is not checked");
            }
            doc3.Save("C:\\CAR_Audition\\param.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the easiest way for me to do this as follows:

```
var doc3 = XDocument.Load(xml_path2);
            var elem = doc3.XPathSelectElement("/Tests/Test[@Name='NavigatorLaunch']");

            if (elem != null)
            {
              elem.Attribute("Value").Value = checkBoxNavigator.Checked ? "1" : "0";
            }
```